# Query to get most popular products ordered by category rank

Tags: elasticsearch

Having the following docs in elasticsearch how is better to query in order to get most popular distinct products (by popularity_score) with it's most ranked category?
Expected result:

1. Category 4 (Product 2 `popularity_score:2` is higher then Product 1 (`popularity_score:10`) and Category 4 `rank:"1.0.0"` is ranked higher than Category 3)
2. Category 5 (Category 5 ranked higher (`rank:2.0.0`) than Category 1(`rank:4.0.0`) and Category 2(`rank:9.0.0`)

```
curl -XPOST 'https://local/test/_doc/' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
 {
"id": 1,
"name": "Category 1",
"rank": "4.0.0",
"product":{"id":1, "name":"Product 1", "popularity_score":10}
 }'

curl -XPOST 'https://local/test/_doc/' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Category 2",
"rank": "9.0.0",
"product":{"id":1, "name":"Product 1","popularity_score":10}
}'

curl -XPOST 'https://local/test/_doc/' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{
"id": 5,
"name": "Category 5",
"rank": "2.0.0",
"product":{"id":1, "name":"Product 1","popularity_score":10}
}'

curl -XPOST 'https://local/test/_doc/' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Category 3",
"rank": "2.0.0",
"product":{"id":2, "name":"Product 2","popularity_score":2}
}'

curl -XPOST 'https://local/test/_doc/' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Category 4",
"rank": "1.0.0",
"product":{"id":2, "name":"Product 2","popularity_score":2}
}'
```

Comment: What is the type for "name" field?

Comment: @Sergey how do you expect to get Category 4 and category 5? Can you please explain this ?

Comment: @ESCoder, I would like to group it by product.id and order by its popularity_score and inside the aggregation by category `rank`. Since `Product 2` has `popularity_score`: 2 and  in `Category 4` `rank is: 1.0.0` which is higher then Category 3, it comes in first place.

Comment: @TusharShahi the name type is keyword but i'm not looking at this point to search by `name`

Comment: @ESCoder what's yours thoughts on it? Is it possible with my data modelling to achieve the results?